# Is it possible to create empty folders using Cloudinary API

Tags: rest, cloudinary

When uploading images with the auto-creation of folders settings is enabled, Cloudinary can create folders.
But, can we create folders using the API?

Comment: See this snippet [support.cloudinary.com...](https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000262905-Create-folders-with-net-api). It looks like including the folder name in the upload path automatically creates the folder.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it requests information regarding what the API can do and not about a specific problem with the API. This would be better suited for the https://support.cloudinary.com support forums.